# iOS Swift insert into sqlite FMDB

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

here is my issue : I have this wine app, that shows the content of my database to the user in a nice tableview. I can get data from it quite easily, using the FMDB executeQuery function, but whenever I try to add something to the SQLite table, it just fails.

Here is the code I use.

```
do
 {
     try sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO wine VALUES (?, ?, ?)", values: [id, name, wineType])
 }
 catch
 {
     print("error \(error)")
 }
```

I've tried putting everything in one string, and then send it as the first parameter, and putting nil as a second parameter, and that also fails. This syntax comes from the [Data Sanitisation section in the FMDB README from github](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

I've found a few similar cases, but the answers were Objective-C. Please note that I am completely new to iOS, I don't know anything about Objective-C, and this is my first Swift app.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You could use a Swift wrapper for SQLite. There are good ones, now, like https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In some cases `executeUpdate` it fails so First try to use `executeQuery` or `executeStatments`to fix the issue.

If it didn't work, In my opinion the proper way for executing sql statement after opening database is:

```
executeUpdate("INSERT INTO wine VALUES ('\(id)', '\(name)', '\(wineType)')")
```

And close database after the statement is successfully executed. What is the type of your id in database ? And is it auto increment ?

What error are you getting in the console ? try to use breakpoint and see whats happening.

**Update**
The previous code is not preferred to use on production environment since it’s subject to SQL injection [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) , in my opinion using FMDB with iOS and the previous code is just ok to use.

Comment: do not form the string by concatenation. What if wineType is equal to "); DROP TABLE wine;"?

Comment: Minus one too, because answer recommends unsafe code, subject to SQL injection. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: @Gwendal, Its better that you modify the answer rather than downvoting it. We need good quality answers so why not helping by editing answers?!

Comment: @Jeyhey,I have updated the answer with your references. Thank you

Comment: In addition to the SQL injection concerns which, depending on the app and context, may or may not be a concern for you, there is also the problem of values containing apostrophes (single quotes) when using this method. I have to imagine it is not very rare for the name of a wine to contain an apostrophe. This would break in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct, may be you want to check if:

- you called `sharedInstance.database!.open()` beforehand
- your table only consist of 3 columns

If you include `FMDatabaseAdditionsVariadic.swift` and `FMDatabaseVariadic.swift` into your project, you can call `executeUpdate` like this:

```
do {
    try sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO wine VALUES (?, ?, ?)", id, name, wineType)
} catch {
    print("error \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note** :- Here i sending you code for Insert record in Database using FMDB in swift.

```
import UIKit

class FMDBDatabaseSignUpVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtFirstNameOutlet: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtLastNameOutlet: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtEMailIDOutlet: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPasswordOutlet: UITextField!

var databasePath = NSString()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths =
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
                                            .UserDomainMask, true).first as String!

    databasePath = (dirPaths as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("swiftDemo.db")

    if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String)  {
        let contactDB = FMDatabase (path: databasePath as String)
        if contactDB == nil {
            print(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())
        }
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func btnSaveAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let contactDB = FMDatabase (path: databasePath as String)
    if contactDB.open() {
        let InsertQry = "insert into userInfo (userFirstName, userLastName,userEmailID,userPassword) values ('\(txtFirstNameOutlet.text!)','\(txtLastNameOutlet.text!)','\(txtEMailIDOutlet.text!)','\(txtPasswordOutlet.text!)')"
        let result = contactDB.executeUpdate(InsertQry, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
        if !result {
            print(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())
        }
        else
        {
            print("Success")
            txtFirstNameOutlet.text=""
            txtLastNameOutlet.text=""
            txtEMailIDOutlet.text=""
            txtPasswordOutlet.text=""
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
    do
 {
     try sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO wine(id, name, wineType) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", values: [id, name, wineType])
 }
 catch
 {
     print("error \(error)")
 }
```